# Arc-length without bounds

Tags: calculus, upper-lower-bounds, arc-length

When I tried to calculate the Arc length of $r = (\cos^3x, \sin^2x)$, I used the arc length formula and got $\cos x \cdot \sin x(3\cos x+2)$. I do not get why we don't need the bounds (range) for the parameters in order to get the length. Could someone help? Thanks!

Comment: Your length depends on the variable $x.$

Comment: So does it mean that I still need the range for x in order to solve this?

Comment: I am wondering if I have made a mistake in determining the length formula regarding x.

Comment: If your arc length depends on $x$ that means the length of the arc depends on how far along the arc you've moved, which is (trivially) true. You need bounds if you have a certain section of that arc you're measuring. If you aren't doing that, the length will depend on how far you want to measure. That's what your result says.

Comment: You do need some sort of bound.  But you might say $2\pi$ is a complete period.  But the arc length is $\int \|dr\| dt $ or in your case  $\int \sin x\cos x\sqrt{9\cos^2x + 4}\ dx$.  What you show is just $dr$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

In parametric for $(x(t),y(t)$, the arc length is given by
$$L=\int_{t_0}^{t_1} \sqrt{\left(\frac {dx}{dt} \right)^2+\left(\frac {dy}{dt} \right)^2}\,dt$$

So, as Doug M commented, the first problem is to compute the antiderivative 
$$f(t)=\int \sin (t)\cos(t)\sqrt{9\cos^2(t) + 4}\, dt$$ where you should notice that $\sin (t)\cos(t)$ is "almost" the derivative of $\cos^2(t)$ which reveals a quite obvious cange of variable.

When you will finish, then just apply to get
$$L=|f(t_1)-f(t_0)|$$

By the way, the curve is entirely defined by $0 \leq t \leq \pi$.